# How to add taints(more than one) using Python's Kubernetes library

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

I'm trying to add k8s taint to the node using python's k8s library.

Used [How to delete a node taint using Python's Kubernetes library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174233/how-to-delete-a-node-taint-using-pythons-kubernetes-library?answertab=active#tab-top)

But by this v3.patch_node() method, previously added taint gets deleted, and the latest taint exists.

How can I add a new taint(can be multiple taints) with the existing taint in the node?

Comment: You could read the existing taints first, and then just append values to that list and pass the whole thing to `patch_node`.

Comment: what will be the behavior of apps which are already deployed with existing taints?
because taints get deleted for some time if I'm not wrong.